# How can I define a constant conditioned to the current domain?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a simple code change in my website, but I don't have much knowledge.

My site current runs a Heroku app that has some Config Vars defined. The app calculates an output base on these variables. The thing is I have the same app running in the main domain (mydomain.com) and in a subdomain (pro.mydomain.com). So I want part of the calculation to use a different variable depending on which domain the user has accessed.

I've tried using window.location.hostname in the constant definition part, but it did not work.

The beginning app.js file looks like this right now:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express')
    , flash = require("express-flash")
    , ADMIN_EMAIL = process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL
    , NOREPLY_EMAIL = process.env.NOREPLY_EMAIL
    , EXPIRY_TIME = parseInt(process.env.EXPIRY_TIME)
    , FEE = parseFloat(process.env.FEE)
```

This is what I've tried and didn't work:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express')
        , flash = require("express-flash")
        , ADMIN_EMAIL = process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL
        , NOREPLY_EMAIL = process.env.NOREPLY_EMAIL
        , EXPIRY_TIME = parseInt(process.env.EXPIRY_TIME)
        , FEE = window.location.hostname === 'pro.mydomain.com' ? parseFloat(process.env.FEE_PRO) : parseFloat(process.env.FEE)
```

What I need is that user who access through mydomain.com get one fee and users who access through pro.mydomain.com get another. I am currently not worried about authentication or anything, doesn't matter if anyone can access both.

Also I am intentionally trying to do this without using a second Heroku app to avoid extra costs.

Comment: As I understand, you are trying to determine domain at server side. And server side is the same for both domains. You need to determine domain for each request.

Comment: OK Valerii, makes sense. And how would you suggest I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment you need to handle it on request level, not globally. Server side is the same for both domains.
On request level you can do it like this:

```
if (req.hostname === 'pro.mydomain.com') {
    ...
}
```

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.hostname